# Remove Spring actuator from my project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring boot project using spring security and Oauth2 and I'm noticing some bad behaviour which could be caused by actuator.
To be sure I want to remove it from the project but I can't find it explicitly mentionned in my Maven dependencies.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: This is an XY problem. What bad behavior do you see? Maybe there is a different solution for that. Also, there are [ways](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2661) to disable it instead. Doesn't seem like a good idea to exclude something that comes out-of-the-box as a dependency.

Comment: what am I doing here? .. actuator /spring is part of active-exhaust in sport car .. I was looking for away to inactive it .. Google took me here 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find where it is with dependencies hiearchy and exclude it.

This official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html) may help you to do so.

Comment: this document is no longer available

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite clear to me whether you want to exclude the actuator dependencies from your classpath or whether you want to disable the behaviour from your container. If it is the latter, you should be able to do so through your application.properties, i.e.:

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false

I am pretty sure you can disable also by using annotations on your spring boot application class as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to print all the transitive dependencies as a tree structure. It's a standard maven-dependency-plugin [mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Once you find the dependency that introduces it use `<dependencyManagement>` section with correct `<exclude>` to remove the actuator from the project.

Comment: The issue is that is brought by spring-boot-starter. Any idea on how to exclude it from there?

Comment: @Monta usually `<dependencyManagement>` is used with correct `<exclude>` however this might depend on your pom.xml.